# How to run a jQuery method for each group of elements

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, loops

So I have this list that uses the same class name on all the items in the list. I have a jQuery plugin that finds the tallest element and makes the heights of all the list items equal to the tallest.

The thing that I want to do is that I want to run the method for each `UL` group. What I mean is that right now jQuery is selecting ALL the `LI` elements even if they are in other Lists and makes them all the same as the tallest one. I only want the list items to be as tall as the tallest element in their list not in other lists.

This is how I call it and it works, but not the way that I'm asking.

```
$j('.list-item').equalHeights(200); //minimum is 200px
```

I tried this but it yields the same results:

```
$j('.lists').find('li').equalHeights(200);
```

I wasn't sure if i had to loop through each `UL` then run the method that way?

HTML:

```
<ul class="lists">
    <li class="list-item">item</li>
    <li class="list-item">item</li>
    <li class="list-item">item</li>
    <li class="list-item">item</li>
</ul>
<ul class="lists">
    <li class="list-item">item</li>
    <li class="list-item">item</li>
    <li class="list-item">item</li>
    <li class="list-item">item</li>
</ul>
<ul class="lists">
    <li class="list-item">item</li>
    <li class="list-item">item</li>
    <li class="list-item">item</li>
    <li class="list-item">item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to loop:

```
$j('.lists').each(function() {
    $j(this).find('li').equalHeights(200);
});
```

Your `$j('.lists').find('li').equalHeights(200);` was close, but it finds all of the `li` elements under *all* of the lists and returns a single jQuery instance containing all of them (so, still the whole set). The above processes each list in isolation.

Comment: um.. actually TJs answer is what i needed. i dont need a function or anything else, just a way to run the method called equalHeights() for each group. the method works already

Answer (score 0):

Loop is the easiest way to do this, as for me.

However, if you need you instruction `$j('.list-item').equalHeights(200);` to work as expected, you may want to write your own analogue of `equalHeights` method to first construct a collection of groups of all `li`s inside one `ul` and then run height-equaling logic for each group separately. Thus, you'll have all your logic inside one method, which is possibly better option in your case.